# handling exceptions IN Action Filters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception

Is there a better way to handle exceptions that occur inside an Action Filter itself in ASP .NET MVC?

There're 2 ways I can think of at the moment.

1. Using a try catch and setting the HTTP Status Error code and message directly when an exception occurs
2. Response.Redirect to the custom error page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may implement [IExceptionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iexceptionfilter.aspx) to separate exception handling from the rest of the filter logic.